# Detect if AdControl (Microsoft Advertising SDK) is clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I tried IsEngagedChanged, PointerPressed/PointerReleased, none of those events is fired when I click the AdControl. (AdRefreshed event does occur)

I am developing an Windows Store App in C#/XAML.

```
<ad:AdControl Height="90" x:Name="ad1" Width="728" AdUnitId="10042998" ApplicationId="d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab" IsEngagedChanged="ad1_IsEngagedChanged_1" AdRefreshed="ad1_AdRefreshed_1" PointerPressed="ad1_PointerPressed_1" />

    private void ad1_IsEngagedChanged_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         //not fired
    }

    private void ad1_AdRefreshed_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         //fired
    }

    private void ad1_PointerPressed_1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         //not fired
    }
```

I want to award the user for clicking on the Ad.

Comment: Yeah, you're missing something, from your post specifically. Your code.

Comment: nothing special about the code

Comment: I think the point of that control is that *Microsoft* knows it got clicked.

Comment: Then why put a IsEngagedChanged event on the control?

Comment: @HansPassant, the IsEngagedChanged event  is part of the AdControl to determine if the user is interacting with the ad.  
From MDSN "Raised when the user clicks the ad, and is interacting with it rather than the app."

Answer (score 1):

The IsEngagedChanged-event does actually fire, but not really when you expect it to. If you use ads which causes the ad to go full-screen (click-to-fullscreen) the IsEngagedChanged-event will fire when a user clicks it. If you use a normal ad (which you did according to your adUnitId) which goes to some link, the event will not fire. It's stupid as hell.

As Walt Ritscher pointed out, this is in the docs:

> Raised when the user clicks the ad, and is interacting with it rather
>   than the app.

Which makes one believe it would get called on any click, but it doesn't. There's so many things missing/"wrong" in the Microsoft Advertising SDK that you wanna cry.

Hope this helped someone.